# Concurrent ThreadPoolExecutor.submit() calls

Tags: java, executorservice, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I have a `ThreadPoolExecutor` whose `submit` method may be called concurrently by multiple threads. I’m wondering how the `ThreadPoolExecutor` would handle this. I don’t see that `submit` is atomic from the source code, although maybe I’m missing something.
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

At submit() `ExecutorService` relies on its `BlockingQueue` for synchronization.

When initializing a executor you have to provide a queue instance which is used to store all submited tasks and is used as source for the thread pool to read from.

For executors initialized from one of the `Executors` fixed size factory methods a `LinkedBlockingQueue` is used internally.

`LinkedBlockingQueue` internally uses a `ReentrantLock` to lock and synchronize when it is offered new entries to store

As long as you work with `java.util.concurrent` implementations for your Queue concurrent submits should work just fine.